# How we can show "No Data Available" message in RDLC Reports via Resources files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0, rdlc

How we can  show "No Data Available" message in RDLC Reports via Resources files if no data is found. Currently we are reflecting message from NoRowsMessage property for a table, matrix, or list
(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645968.aspx).

But we want to show it via Resource files and C# code rather then setting it from Properties of Table. Can anyone please assist. The code (Page_Load) of our control page (.ascx)is mentioned below:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var presenter = (ReportPresenter)Model;

            reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

            reportViewer.Visible = true;
            var   rdlcPath = "~/ReportsRDLC/EmployeeData.rdlc";

            if(presenter.ReportFilter.GroupOption == Resources.Date)
            {
                rdlcPath = "~/ReportsRDLC/EmployeeDatebyDate.rdlc";
            }

            groupOption.SelectedValue = presenter.ReportFilter.GroupOption;
            const string DataSetName = "EmployeeDataSet";

            reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rdlcPath);
            var dataSource = new ReportDataSource(DataSetName, presenter.EmployeeDetails);


            reportViewer.AsyncRendering = false;
            reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
            reportViewer.ShowPrintButton = false;
            reportViewer.ShowRefreshButton = false;
            reportViewer.ShowToolBar = true;
            reportViewer.Height = 600;
            reportViewer.Width = 400;
            reportViewer.ShowPageNavigationControls = false;
            reportViewer.ShowFindControls = false;
            reportViewer.ShowZoomControl = false;
            reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could send the message as a parameter.

You can tell if the report will be empty depending if `presenter.EmployeeDetails` is empty.

```
ReportParameter[] myParameters = new ReportParameter[1];
myParameters[0] = new ReportParameter("pEmptyMessage", presenter.EmployeeDetails.Any() ? "No Data Available"  : string.Empty);

reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(myParameters);
```

On your report you can then display this message as you please, using the parameter. You can even place it in a textbox and decide whether to display it based on the value.

I hope this is of use to you.

---

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that you should add the report parameter with the correct name to your reporter:

[image: Report Parameter Properties]

In the reporter you can then use the parameter as followed : `[@pEmptyMessage]`

```
=Parameters!pEmptyMessage.Value
```

Comment: It is showing this Error for last line: reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(myParameters);
   
   An exception of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that you should define a parameter with the correct name in your reporter. In the example that would be "pEmptyMessage".